# The webpage cannot be found error after detach and attach content database

Tags: sharepoint-server

After detach and attach content database facing "Webpage cannot be found error" in ie and in chrome:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Date: Mon, 27 Jul 2015 06:56:52 GMT
Connection: close
```

And in log:

```
Category        : SiteOrphan
Error           : True
UpgradeBlocking : False
Message         : Database [WSS_Content_DBONE] contains a site (Id = 
                  [798c2f51-4e9e-44bf-bfad-c774a7b563d0], Url = [/]) whose id 
                  is already associated with a different database (Id = 
                  [3637a130-6cf9-4932-8b9c-d85a7030c010], name = 
                  [WSS_Content_DBTWO]) in the site map. Consider deleting one 
                  of these sites which have conflicting ids.
Remedy          : The orphaned sites could cause upgrade failures. Try detach 
                  and reattach the database which contains the orphaned sites. 
                  Restart upgrade if necessary.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to mount the content database after detach attach operation either in Central Administration of using PowerShell:

```
Mount-SPContentDatabase "MyDatabase" -DatabaseServer "MyServer" -WebApplication http://sitename
```

Ref: [Mount-SPContentDatabase](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607581.aspx)

## Edit

From the logs we can see that you have the same site in both Content-DB:s. It suggest that you delete one of them. Preferably the one existing in the first mounted Content-DB, but make sure you back up the databases first so you can restore the site/content if something goes wrong.

Comment: I already mount using powershell, after mount only facing this issue! Any other idea?

Comment: After detach both DBONE and DBTWO, then I mount DBTWO first and its working fine. When mount DBONE later, facing same issue as vice-versa, help pls

Comment: while mounting each content db should point to its own site collection not the same site collection

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did copy of database WSS_Content_DBTWO and connected as WSS_Content_DBONE.

Unfortunately, the ID of site is not changed and it causing problems.

You have to

1. use [Backup-SPSite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/backup-spsite?view=sharepoint-server-ps) from WSS_Content_DBTWO for root site
2. create new content database (called WSS_Content_DBONE) in SharePoint CA
3. create blank root site in new content database
4. use [Restore-SPSite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/restore-spsite?view=sharepoint-server-ps) into new blank site. It will restore backed up site into new content database and there will not be problem with ID.

*Hope this helps! :)*

*If so mark it as answer. Thank you.*